# EditText value in a Service

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service

I'm building an application in which I use a service to create a background process. but I have a problem.
I use an EditText where the user enters a URL, then I will use that url in the service for check the connection to a website every X minutes. But if the user closes the application, the background process crash because the value of the EditText became Null, and logcat give me null pointer exceptions. I pass the value from the activity to the service with an intent, MainActivity code below:

```
public void onClickReadWebPage(View v)
    {


        if(address.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URL String empty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            time = String.valueOf(address.getText());
            i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
            p=PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, i, 0);
            i.putExtra("Address", time);                
            //start the service from here //MyService is your service class name
            startService(i);
        }
```

and this is the service code:

```
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) 
    {   
        Address = intent.getStringExtra("Address");
        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
        task.execute(Address);

        if(report == "false")
        {
            //do my stuff
        }
        else
        {
            //do my stuff
        }
    }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: is not your problem ( at the moment ) - but really looks wrong: if(report == "false")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save the value of `ediText` in `SharedPreferences` and then retrieve them in your `service`

- .See 
  [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)
- Also [Problems using SharedPreferences on a Service (getPreferences doesn't exist on a service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214939/problems-using-sharedpreferences-on-a-service-getpreferences-doesnt-exist-on-a)

Comment: Thank you, SharedPreferences probably is the correct way to store the URL.

Comment: I know, but i wanna try it before. Then i'll do it.

Comment: :) ...that's nice,regards