# Can't get sharedPreferences inside IntentService

Tags: android, intentservice

[Problems using SharedPreferences on a Service (getPreferences doesn't exist on a service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214939/problems-using-sharedpreferences-on-a-service-getpreferences-doesnt-exist-on-a)

This topic didn't helped me, I created keys and saved them in an activity and tried to get them from the IntentService and I couldn't get them, I tried several ways.

Comment: "I couldn't get them, I tried several ways" -- then please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the "several ways" that you tried and explaining what "couldn't get them" means for each.

Answer (score 1):

I am accessing preferences from a Service in one of my apps, here is how I do it:

```
preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            "settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Instead of `settings` you can write something else as well. Should be the same value that you use to access inside the activity.

Comment: thanks , actually I think the problem was that I didn't initiate the variables I sent as defaults, and it made some kind of inner problem that returned null for string's and false for boolean's. not sure about it but this is my conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Just use 
`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(MY_PREFERENCE, null);` from your service. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```